Python DOCX to PDF : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write' docx2pdf
I’m encountering an issue with the docx2pdf library while trying to convert a DOCX file to PDF.
The conversion process completes, but I receive the following error:
2024-08-02 11:44:26,978 - ERROR - Erreur lors de la conversion DOCX en PDF : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
import os
import logging
from docx2pdf import convert

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='conversion.log',
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
)

def convert_docx_to_pdf(docx_path, output_path):
    logging.debug(f"Début de la conversion : {docx_path} -> {output_path}")
    try:
        # Check if DOCX file exists
        if not os.path.exists(docx_path):
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"Le fichier DOCX spécifié n'existe pas : {docx_path}")

        # Convert DOCX to PDF
        convert(docx_path, output_path)
        
        # Check if PDF file was created
        if not os.path.exists(output_path):
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"Le fichier PDF n'a pas été créé : {output_path}")

        logging.info(f"Conversion réussie : {output_path}")
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        logging.error(f"Erreur de fichier : {e}")
    except PermissionError:
        logging.error(f"Erreur de permission lors de la conversion : {docx_path}")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Erreur lors de la conversion DOCX en PDF : {e}")

def main():
    docx_file = r'C:\Users\hbab\Desktop\document.docx'
    pdf_from_docx = r'C:\Users\hbab\Desktop\document.pdf'
    logging.debug(f"Début de la conversion de {docx_file} vers {pdf_from_docx}")
    convert_docx_to_pdf(docx_file, pdf_from_docx)

    if os.path.exists(pdf_from_docx):
        logging.info(f"Le fichier PDF a été créé avec succès : {pdf_from_docx}")
    else:
        logging.error(f"Le fichier PDF n'a pas été créé : {pdf_from_docx}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Name: docx2pdf
Version: 0.1.8
Summary: Convert docx to pdf on Windows or macOS directly using Microsoft Word (must be installed).
Home-page: https://github.com/AlJohri/docx2pdf
Author: Al Johri
Author-email: al.johri@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: C:\Users\hbab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
Requires: pywin32, tqdm
Required-by:
Has anyone encountered this issue before? How can I resolve the 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write' error in docx2pdf? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
I tried using the docx2pdf library to convert a DOCX file to PDF.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Looking at the source code on Github, using the library docx2pdf requires that you have Microsoft Word installed on that computer. Are you sure it is installed?
